# How to get the Reddit iOS app table sort feature

Tags: ios

I'm building an app that has a table that the user can sort based off a few attributes.

I would like to have something similar to the Official Reddit iOS look and feel for table sorting:

[image]

[image]

How would one go about getting that `hot posts` to show at the top of table after you scroll down?

Also is the popup simply a uialert that's sent to the bottom of the screen, or is it a modal view controller most likely?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "hot" and re-order the list accordingly.

Say you have posts on your server that have an average of 15 views. When the user re-orders, you'll only show the posts with 25 views and order them by date.

You simply re-arrange your list of items according to the selected sorting mechanism, which can be an enum.

Before displaying the list, and after choosing a sort mechanism, you just reload all your data using classic if-else logic.

```
if (currentSort == Sort.Hot)
{
      ReorganizeListWithLessThan25Views();
}
if else (currentsort == Sort.New)
{
     ReorganizeListByDateOnly();
}
else 
{
    ReorganizeListWithAllElements();
}

ReloadData();
```

You might as well just use a switch statement, since there might be more sorting choices and it would look a bit cleaner. But that doesn't really change much. I just personally like using switch when I have more than 3 if-else that follow.

Your second question : yes, this is custom action sheet.

Comment: thanks for the input! I was actually asking from more of a UI perspective on how to get that `hot posts` to show